# Getting wrong total hours

Tags: android, datetime, time

I'm really sorry if I ask a stupid question here but I really have no idea to solve :(

In my app, I want to calculate the total hours and finally display on `textView`. I have set different condition in case the start time is more than end time.

```
     int a = SplitTime(objMyCustomBaseAdapter.getFistTime());
     int b = SplitTime(objMyCustomBaseAdapter.getLastTime());
     long difference = 0;
     if (a > b) 
     {
         difference = b + 24 - a;
         Log.e("Tag",difference+"");
         int minutes = (int) ((difference / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
         int hours = (int) ((difference / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
         totalHours.setText((hours + ":" + minutes));
       }
      else
       {
          difference=b-a;
          int minutes = (int) ((difference / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
          int hours = (int) ((difference / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
          totalHours.setText((hours + ":" + minutes));
        }

     public static int SplitTime(String time) {
        try {
               String[] altSplitTime = time.split(":", 3);
               return Integer.valueOf(altSplitTime[1].trim()) * 60 + Integer.valueOf(altSplitTime[2].trim());
             }
        catch (Exception ex)
             {
            return 0;
             }

}
```

Assume `int a` holds `550`, `b` holds `71`, and difference holds `503`.
After that I want to convert it to `hours` and `minutes`, finally display on textView. But I get `0:0` on textView.

What's wrong here ? Did I implemented wrongly ? Can someone give me suggestions on how to solve this ? Appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change it to.

```
int minutes = (int) (difference   % 60);
         int hours = (int) (difference  /60 % 24);
```

Comment: Thanks..it display value on textView now. Can I ask you something that not related to programming? If `time in` is 9am and he works until 1am, does my format provided is correct?

Comment: i dont understand correctly you want to calculate how many hours he is in work?

Comment: Yup. Assume he is work from 9am to 1am,  what is the format I should write?  If he works from 9am to 6pm,  there would be no problem as I can get from b-a

Comment: so a will be int = 9 and b will be int = 1 ? so b - a is the amount of hours he work. so difference is plain = b-a  and you dont need the whole code no? or maybe im getting you wrong?

Comment: `b-a` will be only work if end time(1600) is bigger than start time(0900). If he works from 9am (0900) to 1am (0100), and I use `(b-a)`, I will get a negative value, where the answer should be 16

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that its a problem with your casting. Meaning you call minutes and hours an `int` but they may be returning longs, doubles or floats.

Try changing hours and minutes to a double, long, or float. Then converting it to an Integer later by rounding or casting then.

```
double minutes = ((difference / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
double hours = ((difference / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
//print the values here to your log to ensure they hold a value
Log.v("TIME", "minutes: " + minutes);
Log.v("TIME", "hours: " + hours);
//convert to int here, by rounding or casting.
totalHours.setText((hours + ":" + minutes));
```

Comment: no luck..I get `V/TIME﹕ minutes: 0.0`, `V/TIME﹕ hours: 0.0`. I wonder do I need to add   `SimpleDateFormat format= new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");` ?